Fantasy YA shorter story with a young boy, a monster and a dark forest
So I would have read this probably in the mid-1980s and I recall it being a "longer" short story as one of perhaps three in the book. I was reading a lot of Robert Westall around then too but I don't think it was one of his (having gone through his bibliography here: https://robertwestall.com/books_by_robert_westall.html) but I recall it having a similar "YA Horror" feel as things like "The Scarecrows", etc.
Although I don't remember the other stories, the one I do featured a young boy from a village that is being terrorised by some monster from the forest. Everything is described in very dark terms including the forest itself which is black and impenetrable. I don't recall their being too much death or gore but the implication is that they are fairly powerless against it and that it is virtually invulnerable to their spears, etc. The adults and warriors of the village don't seem to be able to defend against it and the boy, who is more thoughtful, starts to consider other tactics.
I recall that he sneaks into the forest when he hears the monster attacking elsewhere in an effort to find its lair and discovers some broken claws there. He reasons that perhaps the beast is vulnerable to its own "weapons". The writing of this part with the sense of ominous dread at his possible discovery (perhaps combined with my age) absolutely terrified me!
I don't particularly recall the final outcome, other than that it was broadly successful  (using the broken claws for spear tips?). Again, consistent with the "not too much gore" it may have been that the monster was chased off, injured, rather then being killed.
I think the book cover may have been mostly black with possibly a red symbol of some kind on it.
